# C# Split up string representation of a formula

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to using regular expression and am having problems parsing a string. I am working on parsing a Formula given as a string using regular expression.

Currently my regular expression is:

```
string[] formula_substrings = Regex.Split(formula, "(\\()|(\\))|(-)|(\\+)|(\\*)|(/)|(\\s+)")
```

One of the test cases that this regular expression is unable to handle is when the formula has exponents.

Example:

```
Formula = "1e-2 + 5.0"
```

My desired output is

```
["1e-2", "+", "5.0"]
```

but I am getting

```
["1e", "-", "2", "+", "5.0"].
```

I tried changing the regular expression to make sure the character in front of the minus sign ins't an e:

```
string[] formula_substrings = Regex.Split(formula, "(\\()|(\\))|((^e)-)|(\\+)|(\\*)|(/)|(\\s+)")
```

And this is causing problems when the expression is

```
Formula = "5+5-2"
```

It will give the output:

```
["5", "+", "5-2"]
```

When my desired output is

```
["5", "+", "5", "-", "2"]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Also read about greedy (*) and non-greedy (*?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookbehind..

```
Regex.Split(formula, @"(\(|\)|(?<!e|E)-|(?<!e|E)\+|\*|/|\s+)")
                              --------  --------
```